# Autofill text field when combo box value selected

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I wanna ask about JavaScript `onchange` function and PHP.

I have combo box with that value I get from db (MySql), here's my progress :

Here're my database content :

```
member:
  person_name (person one, person two, person three)
  description ("sdsdsdsds","ewewewewe","gfdfdfdff","dfdfdfdfdfS")
```

PHP :

```
  include "conn.php";

  $query = "SELECT person_name FROM member";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  echo "<select name='name'>";
  echo "<option value=''>-Select-</option>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='".$row['person_name']."'>".$row['person_name']."</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
```

So, when I choose one of that value, I want blank textarea,

```
<textarea>"FILLED WITH DESCRIPTION FROM DB BASED ON NAME SELECTED</textarea>
```

Comment: Sorry, do you have any references? @SunilPachlangia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this -

```
 echo "<select name='name' id='sel_id' onchange='fillData()'>";
  echo "<option value=''>-Select-</option>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='".$row['person_name']."'>".$row['person_name']."</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";

  echo "<textarea id='txt_id'></textarea>";

function fillData(){
    var s = document.getElementById("sel_id");
    var val = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("txt_id").innerHTML = val;
}
```

PLEASE NOTE: I have not tested it.